# Combine/Add dictionaries in a list when the values for two dictionary are equal in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to extract a processed list of dictionary values (`List<Dictionary<String,Object>>`) from a raw list dictionary values(`List<Dictionary<String,Object>>`) .

The Raw dict may contain String/Numeric Value

Eg:

```
Dictionary<String, Object> rawListDict = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
rawListDict.Add("Product","Apple");
rawListDict.Add("Region", "West");
rawListDict.Add("Profit", 90);
```

**Raw List:**

Apple West 90

Apple East 10

Apple West 80

**Processed List :**

Apple West 170

Apple East 10

Consider a list with dictionaries having same product and region, I want a single dict by adding the "Profit" when the "Product" & "Region" are same. (i.e) List of Dictionaries with similar items grouped as single dictionary without any duplicates

Note : Raw list can grow beyond 30K entries. :-(

I have implemented a logic by Brute-force Technique and its consuming a lot of memory and time .Is there any way to do it in LINQ style or any other approach to reduce time and memory ?

**Edit : I am preferring Dictionary since the number of members/keys are only known at the run time.**

Code I have Implemented :

```
                    //Get fields which could be used for combining values
                    var nonMeasurableFields = report.datagrid_fields.
                        Where(field => field.dataType.Equals(ImFieldDatatype.STRING_VALUE) || field.dataType.Equals(ImFieldDatatype.DATE_VALUE)).
                        Select(field => field.name).ToList();

                    if (nonMeasurableFields != null && nonMeasurableFields.Count > 0)
                    {
                        #region Outer For Loop

                        for (int index = 0; index < processedData.Count; index++)
                        {
                            var baseDict = processedData.ElementAt(index);

                            Dictionary<String, Object> compareDict = null;

                            #region Recursive Loop

                            for (int recursiveIndex = index + 1; recursiveIndex < processedData.Count; recursiveIndex++)
                            {
                                compareDict = processedData.ElementAt(recursiveIndex);

                                int matchesCount = 0;

                                #region comparison logic

                                foreach (var key in nonMeasurableFields)
                                {
                                    var baseDictValue = baseDict[key];
                                    var compareDictValue = compareDict[key];

                                    if (baseDictValue == null && compareDictValue == null)
                                    {
                                        matchesCount++;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (baseDictValue != null && compareDictValue == null)
                                        {
                                            matchesCount = 0;
                                        }
                                        else if (baseDictValue == null && compareDictValue != null)
                                        {
                                            matchesCount = 0;
                                        }
                                        else if (baseDictValue != null && compareDictValue != null)
                                        {
                                            if (baseDictValue.Equals(compareDictValue))
                                            {
                                                matchesCount++;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                matchesCount = 0;
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                }

                                #endregion

                                #region If Match -- Combine

                                if (matchesCount == nonMeasurableFields.Count)
                                {
                                    #region combine logic

                                    // Combine the two dictionary .. 

                                    processedData.Remove(baseDict);
                                    processedData.Remove(compareDict);

                                    // combine the base and compare dict

                                    Dictionary<String, Object> combinedDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                                    var keyNeededInDict = baseDict.Keys.ToList();

                                    foreach (var key in keyNeededInDict.ToList())
                                    {
                                        if (nonMeasurableFields.Contains(key))
                                        {
                                            combinedDict.Add(key, baseDict[key]);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            Object value = Convert.ToDouble(baseDict[key]) + Convert.ToDouble(compareDict[key]);

                                            combinedDict.Add(key, value);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    processedData.Add(combinedDict);

                                    index = -1; // Resetting the looping index so that the merging works for all values
                                    recursiveIndex = -1; // Ensuring all the values are considered at least once whenever 
                                    // a change is made to the list (i.e merging the dict)
                                    break;
                                    #endregion
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // No matches
                                    // continue to next
                                }

                                #endregion
                            }

                            #endregion
                        }

                        #endregion
                    }
```

**NOTE :** *I will have information of which key(Value for the key) are of string type and Numeric type.
The sample provided is for demonstration purpose only.The keys and values will be only known at the run time.
I am supposed to combine the two dictionaries if the string values are equal.I will add the numeric values while combining it.*

**Edit 2 :** 
All Dictionaries in the list will have same keys
No values will be discarded.Dictionaries with same values will be combined.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Please show input and expected output.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using Dictionaries instead of objects proper?

Comment: _I want a single dict_, just to be sure, the output should be a single dictionary or a list? _I have implemented a logic by Brute-force Technique_, show us what you got already.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I have updated the question and added the sample. The Keys will be known only at the run time.I am supposed to check all the string values and combine the numeric values

Comment: @AlexFilipovici I want list of dictionaries with unique entries formed  by adding dicts with same string values

Comment: @Jodrell Exactly , the keys in the dictionary are unique , The Values of the keys in the list of dictionaries may be same. Need to find which dictionaries share the same value for the specified keys and combine them.

Comment: So in your sample you have as input 3 dictionaries and as output 2?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici Yes .See I have added up the numeric value when the string values are equal. If still my question is un clear . I would necessarily need to edit and re post it again .

Comment: Will all the dictionaries have the same number of KeyValuePairs? If not, how do you choose which dictionary you should discard?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33280/discussion-between-rajmohan-kathiresan-and-alex-filipovici)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have an

```
IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>
```

and you want to merge the dictionaries, based on some key set.

You need to now which keys of the dictionary form the keyset, so you can group the dictionaries appropriately.

You also need need a delegate function to aggragate each of the non key set values.

On that basis, you need a function like this, to do all the work,

```
IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> Merger(
        IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> source,
        IEnumerable<string> keys,
        IDictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<object>, object>> aggregators)
{
    var grouped = source.GroupBy(d => string.Join("|", keys.Select(k => d[k])));

    foreach(var g in grouped)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var first = g.First();
        foreach(var key in keys)
        {
            result.Add(key, first[key]);
        }

        foreach(var a in aggregators)
        {
            result.Add(a.Key, a.Value(g.Select(i => i[a.Key])));
        }

        yield return result;
    }
}
```

---

So, if working with your example data, you'd call it like this

```
var processedDictionaries = Merger(
    rawListDict,
    new[] { "Product", "Region" },
    new Dictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<object>, object>>
        {
            { "Profit", objects => objects.Cast<int>().Sum() }
        });
```

---

If your values are actually string representations of doubles, you might prepare you aggregators like this,

```
var aggregators = new Dictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<object>, object>>();
aggregators.Add(
     "Profit",
     objects => objects.Cast<string>().Sum(s => double.Parse(s)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. In my case , aggregators need to be dynamic and i am having issue with Casting. It doesnt work for int, double/Double. And one more addition is all the time I may not have the aggregators. So I will retain one only dict whose string values are same. By using the Merger its listing duplicate entries also

Comment: @RajmohanKathiresan, I've altered the grouping function which should help with duplicates problem. You will have to define how the aggregation is performed dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lookup = dicList.ToLookup(x => new{
                                    Product = x["Product"], 
                                    Region = x["Region"]});
var condensedDicList = lookup
       .Select(x => new Dictionary<string, object>(){
                         {"Product",x.Key.Product},
                         {"Region",x.Key.Region},
                         {"Profit",x.Sum(d=>(int)d["Profit"])}
        })
       .ToList();
```

but seriously... why not write a class with

```
class MyData
{
    public string Product{get;set;}
    public string Region{get;set;}
    public int Profit{get;set;}
}
```

and save yourself a huge amount of ball-ache.

Comment: Thanks for the sample . Keys are known only at the run time. I will not have any clue about the number of keys.

Eg. I may a Dict with N number of Keys .

Answer (score 0):

In other words, there are some dictionary keys that you want to group on and there is one key that you want to aggregate by taking the sum. The keys are dynamix. (This sound like a dynamic reporting scenario).

```
var groupingKeys = new [] { "Product", "Region" };
var aggKey = "Profit";
List<Dictionary<String,Object>> rows = GetRows(); //provided

var results =
from r in rows
let groupingValues = groupingKeys.Select(key => r[key]).ToArray()
let groupingString = string.Join("|", groupingValues) //HACK - you better use an array comparer
let aggValue = Convert.ToInt32(r[aggKey])
group aggValue by groupingString into g
select new { Key = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum() }
```

Hope that helps. It surely contains bugs but you can probably fix them.

The trick was to first pull out the grouping keys and values out of the dictionary, then use a standard LINQ `GroupBy` to aggregate.

Comment: It works great. I will replace it with array comparer . What If i need to do if my aggKey is also a dynamic list. There may be a situation where there will not be any aggKey value , In that case , the processed list need to have only unique entries (retaining only one copy of the dict which has the same values for the all string value keys)